# Issue with Flat file connection manager

Tags: ssis

I have build an SSIS package to update Oracle database from the data which is coming in Flat Files.This file contains 4 columns part of which shown below:

Airwaybill No Shipper's Ref. No. PU Date courier name
43737729582 30035024201100 13/05/2011 bluedart
43737729571 30035065201100 13/05/2011 bluedart
43737729560 30035029201100 13/05/2011 bluedart
43737729416 30033277201100 13/05/2011 bluedart
43737729420 30033297201100 13/05/2011 bluedart

These flat files are Tab Delimited.My Package Iterates through them and execute them one by one.

My Problem is that I need to press Reset Column on the columns info for each file in the flat file connection manager,than only that file is getting executed otherwise the next line data is getting clubed with last column and getting errored out

Please help me as because if this I am not able to automate my package.

All these text files are being generated from excel sheet by saving them as text delimeted files.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following steps to verify that the data in the flat file is indeed tab delimited and ends with the row delimiter that you have configured in SSIS.

1. Install the software `Notepad++` on your machine. [**Notepad++ download url**](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/release/5.9.2).
2. After you save the Excel file as tab delimited file, open the tab delimited file in `Notepad++`.
3. In Notepad++, select the menu `View` --> `Show Symbol` --> `Show All Characters` as shown in screenshot #**1**.
4. `Orange arrows` represent **`tabs`**. If you notice dots/periods (**`.`**) in orange color, those represent **`spaces`**. **`CR`** text in black background represents `Carriage Return`.  **`LF`** text in black background represents `Line Feed`.
5. Make sure the file looks as shown in screenshot #**2**.
6. If the file looks correct, then in the SSIS package's file connection manager make sure that the row delimiter is **`{CR}{LF}`** and the column delimiter is **`Tab {t}`**. Refer screenshot #**3**.

Hope that helps.

**Screenshot #1:**

[image: 1]

**Screenshot #2:**

[image: 2]

**Screenshot #3:**

[image: 3]

Comment: Thanks Siva,It will help...but when the excel file is converted into text tab delimited,all the extra columns other than these 4 columns are being counted like as shown below:

Comment: Thanks Siva,It will help...but when the excel file is converted into text tab delimited,all the extra columns other than these 4 columns are being counted and CRLF is coming after the last column.Tell me how can I take only the columns which I found and CFLF should be after my last column.....

Comment: In connection manager I dont find an option to select particular columns...In flat file source there is..but I want that connection manager istself only read thefirst four column and add the Row delimiter at the end of last column...